# C# Unable to get string variable from a method

Tags: c#, variables, methods

I am trying to set a string variable in a method, then call that variable later on a button click event to populate a text box, but I am getting an error calling that string variable stating it does not exists in the current context.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static string MethodGBSizeDueEstimate(string stDueTime)
    {
        DateTime dtDueTimeRounded;
        DateTime dtDueTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dtDueTime;
        decimal dFileSize = Convert.ToDecimal(txtFileSize.Text);
        if (dFileSize > 2 && dFileSize <= 7)
        {
            if (dtDueTimeNow.Minute > 30)
            {
                dtDueTime = dtDueTimeNow.AddHours(9);
                dtDueTimeRounded = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDueTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 tt"));
                stDueTime = Convert.ToString(dtDueTimeRounded);
            }
            if (dtDueTimeNow.Minute < 30)
            {
                dtDueTime = dtDueTimeNow.AddHours(8);
                dtDueTimeRounded = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDueTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 tt"));
                stDueTime = Convert.ToString(dtDueTimeRounded);
            }
            if (dtDueTimeNow.Minute == 30)
            {
                dtDueTime = dtDueTimeNow.AddHours(8);
                dtDueTimeRounded = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDueTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:30 tt"));
                stDueTime = Convert.ToString(dtDueTimeRounded);
            }
        }
        return stDueTime;
    }

    private void btnGenerateEboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtnGB.Checked)
        {
            MethodGBSizeDueEstimate(stDueTime);
        }
        if (rbtnNative2Rel.Checked)
        {
            txtEboardText.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + stDueTime);
        }
    }
```

The error is on stDueTime, saying it doesn't exist in current context on the click event.

Comment: why are you passing `stDueTime` as an argument if you are setting and returning it?

Comment: Please show where you are getting the error instead of requiring everyone to examine every line of your code.

Comment: Also MethodGBSizeDueEstimate should not be static if txtFileSize is a control.

Comment: It seems to me that you never declare that variable inside the click event handler. Do you have declared it somewhere else?

Comment: Posted code would not even compile as `stDueTime` does not exist in `btnGenerateEboard_Click` method

Comment: The input is wrong. `MethodGBSizeDueEstimate` should receive as parameter a string for example: SomeTextBox.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your method `MethodGBSizeDueEstimate()` a little bit. I removed the input parameter `stDueTime` because it is pointless. Just let the method `MethodGBSizeDueEstimate()` return `Convert.ToString(dtDueTimeRounded)` and assign it to the variable `stDueTime` which is declared in the `btnGenerateEboard_Click` event:

```
    public static string MethodGBSizeDueEstimate()
    {
        DateTime dtDueTimeRounded = new DateTime();
        DateTime dtDueTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dtDueTime = new DateTime();
        decimal dFileSize = Convert.ToDecimal(txtFileSize.Text);
        if (dFileSize > 2 && dFileSize <= 7)
        {
            if (dtDueTimeNow.Minute > 30)
            {
                dtDueTime = dtDueTimeNow.AddHours(9);
                dtDueTimeRounded = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDueTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 tt")); 
            }
            else if (dtDueTimeNow.Minute < 30)
            {
                dtDueTime = dtDueTimeNow.AddHours(8);
                dtDueTimeRounded = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDueTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 tt"));
            }
            else
            {
                dtDueTime = dtDueTimeNow.AddHours(8);
                dtDueTimeRounded = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDueTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:30 tt"));
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToString(dtDueTimeRounded);
    }

    private void btnGenerateEboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stDueTime;
        if (rbtnGB.Checked)
        {
            stDueTime = MethodGBSizeDueEstimate();
        }
        if (rbtnNative2Rel.Checked)
        {
            txtEboardText.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + stDueTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This gets me closer I think, however the line at the end of the method

Comment: This gets me closer I think, however the line at the end of the method "return Convert.ToString(dtDueTimeRounded);" dtDueTimeRounded Errors saying Use of Unassigned Local Variable.

Comment: Alternatively I just figured out I also can fix it by assigning a default value to dtDueTimeRounded like such "DateTime dtDueTimeRounded = default(DateTime);"

Comment: @Nickel sure that can fix it too, but checking for (dtDueTimeNow.Minute == 30) is pointless

Comment: Absolutely, you rock, I have been racking my brain for hours on this one... created my account here to get this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

In your `btnGenerateEboard_Click` method, you are passing a variable `stDueTime` to `MethodGBSizeDueEstimate`. But this variable has not been defined in this method or at the class level.

Therefore, the variable is undefined, just as the error is telling you.

In C#, you must declare all variables before you can use them.

```
private void btnGenerateEboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stDueTime;

    if (rbtnGB.Checked)
    {
        MethodGBSizeDueEstimate(stDueTime);
    }
    if (rbtnNative2Rel.Checked)
    {
        txtEboardText.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + stDueTime);
    }
}
```

Also note: if you want a method to modify an argument, you need to pass that argument using the `ref` or `out` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`stDueTime` is local to the `MethodGBSizeDueEstimate` method.

You need to make is available at a class level, maybe as a class member?

```
public string stDueTime { get; set; }
```

Of course, you'd need to make sure you set this by whatever calls `MethodGBSizeDueEstimate`.